# sed + append text at end of a specific line but before specific character

Tags: linux, bash, sed, rhel

I want to add the text `scsi_mod.scan=sync` on the end of the line that start with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` and append the text at the end of the line but before the character `"`.

In case `scsi_mod.scan=sync` already exist then `sed` should not append an additional `scsi_mod.scan=sync`.

We did the following

```
sed -i '/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX/s/$/ scsi_mod.scan=sync/' /etc/default/grub

GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=VG/LV_root rd.lvm.lv=VG/lv_swap ipv6.disable=1 rhgb quiet scsi_mod.scan=sync" scsi_mod.scan=sync
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```

but as you can see from the example above, we not succeeded to append the text before `"`.

The expected results should be like this

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=VG/LV_root rd.lvm.lv=VG/lv_swap ipv6.disable=1 rhgb quiet scsi_mod.scan=sync" 
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```

Comment: As an aside, the `,g` flag is incorrect (but harmless) in `'s, release .*$,,g'`. Because of the `.*` wildcard, the regex can only match once on every line, and so asking `sed` to replace all the occurrences on each line is simply redundant, as well as a (very minor) inefficiency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU `sed` you can try:

```
sed -i '/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX/{/\<scsi_mod.scan=sync"$/!s/"$/ scsi_mod.scan=sync"/}' /etc/default/grub
```

If you want to skip the additio if `scsi_mod.scan=sync` is anywhere in the line, not only at the end:

```
sed -i '/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX/{/\<scsi_mod.scan=sync\>/!s/"$/ scsi_mod.scan=sync"/}' /etc/default/grub
```

Comment: Other than the details of the operation of the `-i` flag (as in, it is supported, and doesn't require an argument, like it does on BSD/MacOS) I don't think anything here is specific to GNU `sed`.

Comment: @tripleee The command grouping `{...}` is not supported by all `sed` as it is in GNU `sed`.  With e.g. BSD `sed`you'll need `-e '...' -e '}'`.

Comment: Oh that's true, you might need newlines or semicolons in odd places with other `sed` implementations. A simple workaround is to refactor to `/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX/!b;/scsi_mod\.scan=sync"$/!s...`

Comment: Good workaround. But `\<...\>` (needed for the second case) is not POSIX. BSD `sed` supports `[[:<:]]...[[:>:]]` but that's not POSIX neither.

Comment: Hmm. Just tested the workaround with the `sed` that comes with macOS (FreeBSD?) and it doesn't work. The semicolon is not supported and must be replaced with a newline (or split in 2 `-e '...'`). According POSIX: _Editing commands **other than** {...}, a, b, c, i, r, t, w, :, and # can be followed by a <semicolon>_

Comment: True, the MacOS `sed` is pesky in that way (the `b` label extends to the end of line, basically)

Answer (score 0):

`sed -i '/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX/s/"$/ scsi_mod.scan=sync"/' /etc/default/grub`

Comment: what in case scsi_mod.scan=sync already defend

Comment: just found there is some edition in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Given this input file which has a couple of rainy-day cases added where `scsi_mod.scan=sync` is already present in a couple of locations:

```
$ cat file
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=VG/LV_root rd.lvm.lv=VG/lv_swap ipv6.disable=1 rhgb quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=VG/LV_root rd.lvm.lv=VG/lv_swap ipv6.disable=1 rhgb quiet scsi_mod.scan=sync"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=VG/LV_root rd.lvm.lv=VG/lv_swap ipv6.disable=1 scsi_mod.scan=sync rhgb quiet"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```

then using any awk we can see it only modifies the one line that you want to be modified:

```
$ awk -v new='scsi_mod.scan=sync' '/^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=/ && !index($0,new) { sub(/"$/,""); $0=$0 " " new "\""} 1' file
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=VG/LV_root rd.lvm.lv=VG/lv_swap ipv6.disable=1 rhgb quiet scsi_mod.scan=sync"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=VG/LV_root rd.lvm.lv=VG/lv_swap ipv6.disable=1 rhgb quiet scsi_mod.scan=sync"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=VG/LV_root rd.lvm.lv=VG/lv_swap ipv6.disable=1 scsi_mod.scan=sync rhgb quiet"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```